# Send and Receive DIME attachments with SOAP using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, soap, attachment, savon

I am successfully using Ruby with Savon to communicate with a set of SOAP services, but it turns out that in order to send and receive attachments the service expects them to use DIME encapsulation. Has anyone managed this using Ruby? If not, what would be a recommended way to approach this problem? This communication is only one part of a Rails application, so ideally the solution would be integrated with the rest of the application.